# How do you use FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms with Visual Studio 2010 and Windows 7?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, encryption, fips

I've enabled FIPS compliance mode in Windows 7, but now my code fails to compile with the following error:

```
Source file 'whatever.cs' could not be opened ('This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms.')
```

I'm using SHA1 (hashing) and TripleDes (encryption) encryption.
I also tried SHA512 and AES (256 bit key).

I can't get the project to build any more, but I need to compile it to use FIPS Compliant algorithms.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try making a blank C# app and compiling it, it should fail for the same reason. Ultimately the problem is Visual Studio, not your code. Follow the [instructions here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/brijs/issue-getting-this-implementation-is-not-part-of-the-windows-platform-fips-validated-cryptographic-algorithms-exception-while-building-outlook-vsto-add-in-in-vs-2010) and add this to your IDE's config file (`Devenv.exe.config`/`VCSExpress.exe.config`/`vbexpress.exe.config`):

```
<enforceFIPSPolicy enabled="false"/>
```

This doesn't mean that your app isn't running in FIPS compliant mode, it means that Visual Studio isn't now. Non-compliant code will still compile but if it tries to execute you'll receive an `System.InvalidOperationException` exception.

I think, but don't know for sure, that the algorithms that VS uses to generate certain hashes in libraries isn't actually FIPS compliant.

Comment: You can also try closing all open files in the IDE and then building.  Someone wrote up the issue recently at Microsoft Connect:  https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/644602/c-solution-will-not-build-with-fips-compliant-security-turned-on-and-some-source-files-open-in-ide

Comment: Setting that to false will prevent the CLR from throwing InvalidOperationExceptions from the constructor of uncertified algorithms and implementations.  I'm not sure this is what you want to do if you are required to actually use FIPS certified algorithms.

Comment: @SwDevMan81, that is true to a degree. However, that setting will only affect Visual Studio and not the program being created within. If you turn this policy on for VS and try to use MD5 you will get an error.

Comment: The workaround in the link that indiv posted seems to work for me.  If I close all the files, it builds successfully.

Comment: Ugh.  It's *enforceFIPSPolicy*, not *enableFIPSPolicy*.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

[This](http://blog.aggregatedintelligence.com/2007/10/fips-validated-cryptographic-algorithms.html) has a list of FIPS compliant algorithms.  A more complete list is [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc750357.aspx)

> **FIPS compliant Algorithms:**
>
> *Hash algorithms*
>
> HMACSHA1
>
> MACTripleDES
>
> SHA1CryptoServiceProvider
>
> *Symmetric algorithms (use the same key
> for encryption and decryption)*
>
> DESCryptoServiceProvider
>
> TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider
>
> *Asymmetric algorithms (use a public
> key for encryption and a private key
> for decryption)*
>
> DSACryptoServiceProvider
>
> RSACryptoServiceProvider

So you will need to use `SHA1CryptoServiceProvider` and `TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider` to be FIPS compliant

Comment: When using that combination of algorithms I still receive the error I listed above.

Comment: As indiv pointed out you might need to close all the files and restart VS.  You might even want to create a new csproj and sln files.

Comment: I believe HMACSHA1 corresponds to SHA1CSP algorithm. I hate how .net documentation doesn't tell you what algorithms official names are, and what version is approved by FIPS etc.

Answer (score 0):

> You can also try closing all open files in the IDE and then building. Someone wrote up the >issue recently at Microsoft Connect: connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/644602/… – indiv

That also worked for me with Visual Studio 2010.  In my case I had to close all open files and also restart Visual Studio